# How to add function in controller

Tags: php, function, frameworks

I'm using Kumbia framework and i'm trying to add function  `ordenar_array()` in controller for use in diferents locations inside controller.

But when i try tu call this function, explorer tell me that this function has undefined.

**Error:**
Fatal error: Call to undefined function ordenar_array() in C:\xampp\htdocs\shbarcelona\app\controllers\whoweare_controller.php on line 38

I can add functions within a controller?

How?

Edit: All Controller code.

```
class WhoweareController extends ApplicationController
{
    public $staff;
    public $prueba;
    public $selectedCategory;
    public $experiences;
    public $offices;
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
    }

    public function ordenar_array() { 
      $n_parametros = func_num_args(); // Obenemos el número de parámetros 
      if ($n_parametros<3 || $n_parametros%2!=1) { // Si tenemos el número de parametro mal... 
        return false; 
      } else { // Hasta aquí todo correcto...veamos si los parámetros tienen lo que debe ser... 
        $arg_list = func_get_args(); 

        if (!(is_array($arg_list[0]) && is_array(current($arg_list[0])))) { 
          return false; // Si el primero no es un array...MALO! 
        } 
        for ($i = 1; $i<$n_parametros; $i++) { // Miramos que el resto de parámetros tb estén bien... 
          if ($i%2!=0) {// Parámetro impar...tiene que ser un campo del array... 
            if (!array_key_exists($arg_list[$i], current($arg_list[0]))) { 
              return false; 
            } 
          } else { // Par, no falla...si no es SORT_ASC o SORT_DESC...a la calle! 
            if ($arg_list[$i]!=SORT_ASC && $arg_list[$i]!=SORT_DESC) { 
              return false; 
            } 
          } 
        } 
        $array_salida = $arg_list[0]; 

        // Una vez los parámetros se que están bien, procederé a ordenar... 
        $a_evaluar = "foreach (\$array_salida as \$fila){\n"; 
        for ($i=1; $i<$n_parametros; $i+=2) { // Ahora por cada columna... 
          $a_evaluar .= "  \$campo{$i}[] = \$fila['$arg_list[$i]'];\n"; 
        } 
        $a_evaluar .= "}\n"; 
        $a_evaluar .= "array_multisort(\n"; 
        for ($i=1; $i<$n_parametros; $i+=2) { // Ahora por cada elemento... 
          $a_evaluar .= "  \$campo{$i}, SORT_REGULAR, \$arg_list[".($i+1)."],\n"; 
        } 
        $a_evaluar .= "  \$array_salida);"; 
        // La verdad es que es más complicado de lo que creía en principio... :) 

        eval($a_evaluar); 
        return $array_salida; 
      } 
    } 

    public function index()
    {//Bookingsend::new_pdf_turismo('6375');
        if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=='88.2.48.198'){


        }   
        $this->javascripts[] = 'http://www.shbarcelona.com/javascript/whoweare.js';
        $this->javascripts[] = 'http://www.shbarcelona.com/javascript/jquery-fancybox.js';
        $this->javascripts[] = 'http://www.shbarcelona.com/javascript/jquery-scrollTo.js';
        $this->javascripts[] = 'http://www.shbarcelona.com/javascript/autoFancybox.js';
        $this->styleSheets[] = 'http://www.shbarcelona.com/css/jquery-fancybox.css';
        $this->styleSheets[] = array('path'=>'http://www.shbarcelona.com/css/jquery-fancybox-mobile.css', 'mobile' => true, 'media' => 'all');

        $this->javascripts[] = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false';

        $staff = new Staff();

        $service = new GhPro();

        $this->departamentos = Language::getTs('departamentos');

        $this->prueba = $service->getStaff();

        $this->prueba = ordenar_array($this->prueba, 'foto_visible');

        $this->selectedCategory = $this->action_name;
        $this->staff[0] = $staff->getStaffFromDept(array(1, 2));
        $this->staff[1] = $staff->getStaffFromDept(array(3, 4));
        $this->staff[2] = $staff->getStaffFromDept(5);
        $this->staff[3] = $staff->getStaffFromDept(6);
        $this->staff[4] = $staff->getStaffFromDept(7);
        $this->staff[5] = $staff->getStaffFromDept(8);

        $this->offices[0] = $this->config['maps']['oficina1'];
        $this->offices[1] = $this->config['maps']['oficina2'];
    }

    public function philosophy()
    {
        $this->view = 'index';
        $this->index();
    }
    public function project()
    {
        $this->view = 'index';
        $this->index();
    }
    public function ourAgencies()
    {
        $this->view = 'index';
        $this->index();
    }
    public function internationalTeam()
    {
        $this->view = 'index';
        $this->index();
    }
    public function references()
    {
        $this->view = 'index';
        $this->index();
    }

    public function debug(){
        $this->view = '_index';
        $this->index(); 
    }

    public function experiences()
    {
        $experiences = new Experiences();
        $this->experiences = $experiences->getExperiences();
    }

    public function architectureDepartment()
    {
        $this->javascripts[] = 'http://www.shbarcelona.com/javascript/architectureDepartment.js';
    }

}
```

Comment: is there is class include in `whoweare_controller.php` ?

Comment: show your calling code.

Comment: You probably need to call `$this->ordenar_array()`...!? Also, WTF are you doing with that `eval` there...?!?

Comment: Yeah, that's not the problem.

Comment: $this->prueba = ordenar_array($this->prueba, 'foto_visible');

Comment: deceze you read the error? Call to UNDEFINED function. The call is made, reflect before comment.

Comment: please add your controller full..(class and that including function)

Comment: Have you *tried* my suggestion...?! Rule out possibilities before retorting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
class <Clssname> extends CI_Controller
{
   public function __construct()
   {
   }
   public function ordenar_array()
  {
     <add your code here...>
  } 
}
```

Comment: the class name it's correct. is the same on one side than the other.

Comment: whoweare_controller.php change as whowearecontroller.php then try